# Creating a build on windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I want to make a build (like APK) of my windows phone 8 app for testing. How can i do so.?

Answer (score 3):

When you Run the Windows Phone 8 app in VS 2012, an XAP file is created in the Bin folder of your app. Its similar to the apk file of Android app. But you cannot directly install this in the phone.

You need a developer account to developer unlock the device for testing. You can test the app in Emulator any way. You can also make use of the Beta testing feature of the Windows Phone marketplace, but again you need a developer account for this as well.

UPDATE:

You can get a developer account from the [Windows Phone Developer site](http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/dashboard) @ $99.

And after getting the developer account, Open the "Windows Phone Developer Registration" tool from your start menu and unlock your device, by following the steps mentioned in that tool

Comment: but how can I run the XAP file(MyApp_Debug_AnyCPU.xap) on emulator, when I try to open the XAP file it asks me to choose the application to open it with.

Comment: You can use "Application Deployment" tool to do that. But, you can also do that from your VS. Either by pressing F5 or by clicking on the Emulator option from the debugging menu at the top

Answer (score 2):

You actually can deploy a XAP file to the phone, provided it is developer unlocked. The tool to do this comes as part of the SDK. Just go to Windows Phone Developer Tools -> Application Deployment. Then you can browse and select the XAP file you want to install. As mentioned above, you XAP file might be in the bin folder, but it could also be in the Debug folder, depending on your configuration. In Visual Studio, to the left of the debug icon (green arrow) you will see a drop down list of deployment options. Here you can choose if you want to deploy to the phone or to the emulator. You can also chose if you want to deploy in debug or production mode.

Comment: Thanks Sadify for detailed answer, How can I do developer unlocked? and How Can I get a developers account for windows phone 8 development?

Comment: I just need to run the app on device, dont want to submit it to app store right now. so do i really need a developers account for this?

Comment: @SameeMir In my answer, I mentioned that you need a developer account to test on the device.