# Deploy private app to windows 8 phone

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you install you own apps on your windows 7 phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229029/can-you-install-you-own-apps-on-your-windows-7-phone)
>   [Sideloading apps on Windows 8 Pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008252/sideloading-apps-on-windows-8-pro)

I am planing to buy and windows 8 phone and port some apps for private use to the system. I however read [this](http://blogs.tieto.com/mobileworld/2012/08/28/windows-phone-8-app-deployment/) article about the deployment process, which scared me off. If I understood the article correctly, you can only let Microsoft check your apps before they are accessible to everyone over the marketplace, or you use some overkill enterprise deployment eco-system which also requires all kinds of vetting processes. Is there a way just to create an installation package, put it on the sd card and then install it, without any additional overhead? And maybe hand the app to a few friends, that they can also use it.

I come from an android background where such an easy installation process is common. How does that compare to Windows 8 phone? Is there maybe some development mode? Devs must at least be able to debug their apps on the phone... I really can't find too much information on the internet, which is odd.

**EDIT:** I just read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669696/test-windows-phone-8-app-on-actual-device?rq=1) that you require a pricy dev account for testing apps on the phone. After installing the required Windows 8 OS to be able to install Visual Studio for the Windows 8 phones development, my emulator won't start because my PC doesn't support some odd virtualization stuff. That makes it really easy to develop apps...

Comment: Look into sideloading apps.

Comment: have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008252/sideloading-apps-on-windows-8-pro - it's got some info for you. As well as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719671/creating-a-build-on-windows-phone-8?rq=1

Comment: I should add. If you're a student you can get a free Dev License to do all of this if you join the Dreamspark program.

Comment: Thanks, that really sucks. Even the people over at xda don't know how to sideload apps. I'll stay with Android until WP9, maybe MS has learnt their leason until then. These mayor dampers will never make a functioning app eco-system feasible.

Comment: @JustinAngel that's about WP7, this is WP8, however the answers are similar :(

Comment: The answers are pretty identical. WP8 also offers company/enterprise app deployment but those also require a WP8 DevCenter company account. Overall, deploying to a phone requires a developer account.